# How to find the nearest point in the coordinate system

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbour

There are so many points in the coordinate system. When a specific point is given in the coordinate system, I want to find the closest point to the straight line distance. For example, if you have 800 points, calculate the distance 800 times and find the smallest value. But I want to make more efficient algorithm that doesn't execute 800 times due to that it might be sorted in a certain order before searching.
That is, if the points is put in a certain order, 
 Could you recommend some notions?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a set $S$ of points in some space (do you have a specific dimension ?), and a point $x$, and you want to find the point of $S$ that is the closest to $x$ ?

If this is indeed what you are trying to do, have a look at [K-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and [Voronoï tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). These methods are based on space partitioning to make queries faster.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GBat's answer, you can also take a look at [binary space partitioning (BSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), like $k$-d tree it needs precomputation beforehand, but once the structure is created, each search can be done in $O(\log n)$.